Looking for a tool for visualising potential can bus data in binary log file
I have some log files that I was able to record from a device that I believe is running a CAN bus (standard frame not extended).
There is no possibility of real time physical access to the bus.
I'm hampered by searches for CAN bus decoding resulting in either python based research projects or for software that expects to monitor the bus directly and doesn't work from externally collected files.
Obviously the first step is to confirm that the data looks like can bus data but most binary data file viewers view in hex which is 8 bit based while the can bus packets don't conform to that format.
I'm looking for something that lets me visualise similar to what I would see if I was running the signal through the digital channels of an oscilloscope.
I could write it myself but presume that there has to be something out there already to do it and I want to avoid playing with graphics libraries in c# LOL
A shot of the hex data

Visual example of the type of view of the data i'm hoping to get. Obviously this data is single channel.


Load your bin into WinOls https://www.evc.de/en/download/down_winols.asp and use the 2D View
